# How to make an image visible for a specific area in css?

Tags: css

```css
.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.text-block{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 135px;
    right: 0;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="img-block" style="overflow: hidden;">
                <img src="https://www.gobble.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/2020_05_19_Gobble3187_LCDP_PeruvianBruss_Steak-edited-1-768x768.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="">
                <img src="https://www.gobble.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/our-plans__circle-c231cb9159b6dfc388cfbad30679fb1c.svg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="position: absolute;right: -30px;top: 60px;width: 163px;height: 157px;">
            </div>

            <div class="card-img-overlay text-white" style="overflow: hidden !important;">
                <h1 class="card-title text-start">Classic Dinner</h1>
                <div class="text-block" style="">
                    <p class="card-textd" style="">
                        15-MIN DINNER KITS DELIVERED
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Get dinner on the table in just 15 minutes with our classic recipes & freshly prepped seasonal ingredients.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up Today</a>
                <br>
                <a href="#" class="">View Pricing</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want the green background image just only for the image area but I can't make it hidden for the rest of the area. How can I do it?
Here's how I've tried but I want something like this in the below picture. I want the green image only visible to the image area
[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="https://www.gobble.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/our-plans__circle-c231cb9159b6dfc388cfbad30679fb1c.svg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="position: absolute;right: -30px;top: 60px;width: 163px;height: 157px;clip: rect(0px, 130px, 100px, 0px);">`

To that image add `clip: rect(0px, 130px, 100px, 0px);`

Comment: Thanks. It's working but it's not responsive. Can you please tell me how to make it responsive?

Comment: You need to make the layout responsive. It doesn't depend on the image only.